# Ошибка при include

Tags: node.js, ejs

Есть шаблонизатор news.ejs и с помощью строчки

```html
<% include blocks/header.ejs %>
```

В него добавляется шапка сайта. Вроде все в порядке, но выдает ошибку:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in ...\pr\views\news.ejs while
> compiling ejs

Где я ошибся, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, все дело в синтаксисе.
Теперь правильно будет писать:

```html
<%- include('blocks/header'); -%>
```